# I need to select only a part of the string

Tags: python

### code =    F0000090C9

### code =    F0000090D7

My question is, how can i pick just the code at this string? starting on F and ending on the last number, i don't want the "code = " part.
I'm trying to do it on Python 3.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
I recommend that you work through a tutorial on Python strings; SO is not intended to replace existing educational resources.

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex.

**Ex:**

```
import re

lst = ['code = F0000090C9', 'code = F0000090D7']
for i in lst:
    print(re.match(r"code\s*=\s*(.+)", i).group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
F0000090C9
F0000090D7
```

Answer (score -1):

There's 2 ways to do this

**First:**

If your string is `a="code = F0000090C9"` and is standardised everywhere such a string occurs i.e it's always `"code = F.."` and not randomised like `"code= F.."` or `"code =F..."` , then you know the relevant part of your string starts at index 7 .
So you can do `new_string = a[7:]`

**Second:**

You can directly find the starting point of your code provided it always starts with an F

```
a="code = F00..."
i = a.index('F')
new_String=a[i:]
```

Comment: There's no guarantee that the code always starts with `F`.

Comment: In that case you will have to go with the first method and make sure your string starts exactly like `"code = <code>"` , with those same number of spaces and everything

Comment: As shown in the other answer, there's no need to make any fragile assumptions to parse a string.